# Does $\mathbb E(X_1)\geq\mathbb E(X_2)$ imply $\mathbb E(\textbf1_{X_1>1})\geq\mathbb E(\textbf1_{X_2>1})$ for real-valued random variables $X_1,X_2$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes

Does $\mathbb E(X_1)\geq\mathbb E(X_2)$ imply $\mathbb E(\textbf1_{X_1>1})\geq\mathbb E(\textbf1_{X_2>1})$ for real-valued random variables $X_1,X_2$?

**Edit:** $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the same distribution with different sets of parameters and completely independent. (Sorry, I completely jumbled the correct formulation of this question.)

How can I prove or disprove the statement?

Comment: Disprove. Counterexamples.

Comment: Re the Edit: "the same distribution with different sets of parameters" No precise meaning. "completely independent" Completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your additional conditions, still false. Suppose $X_2$ has a normal $(0,1)$ distribution, so that $E(X_2)=0$. Now take $X_1$ to have a normal $(1/2, \sigma^2)$ distribution (so $E(X_1)> E(X_2)$) but with $\sigma$ so tiny that $P(X_1>1) < P(X_2>1)$.

Comment: This is the exact kind of counterexample I was searching for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$X_1=0$ almost surely. $X_2 \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(-2,2)$. Then $0<1/4$.

Comment: You should make it clear that you are defining a counterexample to the proposed statement.

Comment: Really sorry, I forgot some information in the OP.

Comment: You are right; but Did already wrote it in the comment, that is why I didn't write anything else...

Comment: @nettle if they have the same distribution (and you do not need independence), then both values are exactly equal.

Comment: I'm not thinking straight, let me reformulate... My bad.